# How can i develop an android application that can use the device in build iris scanner

Tags: android, biometrics, iris-recognition

I am developing a system to identify patients using fingerprint and iris (Retinal) authentication. But the available iris scanners are too expensive for the project. My requirement is to use an Iris scanner on my android device for authentication.

I searched around the internet and couldn't find any solution for this.

Comment: That is impractical. In Android, biometrics is used for device authentication, and *only* for device authentication. An app cannot use it for other purposes.

Comment: https://seap.samsung.com/content/using-iris-scans-secure-mobile-solutions I saw this but it seems to be deprecated.

Comment: It is not part of standard Android. There may be specific devices that offer other uses for their iris scanners, but those capabilities will require device-specific SDKs (like that one) and would require compatible devices.

Comment: Yeah. I need something like that actually. Someone with experiance in this kind of project should know about these SDKs. There is not much documentation on this topic sadly.